# Некоторые программы нагружают процессор на 100%

Tags: ubuntu

На Ubuntu 20.04 периодически некоторые программы начинают грузить все ядра процессора на 100% и компьютер зависает. Сначала такое было только со скайпом, сегодня то же самое сделал десктопный телеграм. Похоже как будто программа словила бесконечный цикл.

Сталкивался ли еще кто-нибудь с такой проблемой? С чем это может быть связано?

Comment: Чё `htop` показывает?

Comment: ps -aux --sort -pcpu в студию

Comment: Поставьте себе https://github.com/ramboxapp/community-edition/releases/download/0.7.7/Rambox-0.7.7-linux-amd64.deb Там все в одном флаконе

Comment: @donRumata htop показывает, что скайп 300% процессора занимает

Comment: @JohanPalych как случится снова, выложу